# Login page for a web application running on Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, authentication

I am creating simple web application. 
There is some public data, and managed data.
Admin is logging in when performing some actions with private data.

Web application server: Tomcat.

Database server: MySQL.

The question is what is best practice to do login verification.

Should I:

a) login be used with some XML files like *web.xml*`/`*context.xml*, maybe using *tomcat-users.xml*? In this case I think Tomcat admins can easily manage (add/remove/change pass) users.

b) use MySQL db table like users. But then it is managed by DB admins. And well is it OK, to put users/passwords in some DB? Maybe should they be encrypted.

Maybe there's some other way.

Limitation is if some software is needed, this must be a freeware.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is the way to go. Ofcourse you need to store passwords hashed in the database. When the user logs in, hash his inputted password and compare it to the (already hashed) password retrieved from the database in order to know if his provided password is correct.

You can keep track of permissions in the user table by adding permission colums. Add columns 'Add', 'Remove', 'ChangePassword', ... and set them 0 or 1 to know if the corresponding user has the permission to do the action.